# How do I terminate the script once 'q' is pressed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, networking, sys

Below is a complete script I am trying to automate the process of pinging multiple routers and to do that every 2 hrs but I also want the ability to terminate it at any given time.

```
def start():
    for file_name in file_list:
        unrechable = []
        rechable = []
        print("Processing:"+file_name,end="\n")
        open_file(file_name, rechable, unrechable)

        if len(unrechable) > 0:
            print("These IP from " + file_name + " are Unrechable:")
            for i in unrechable:
                print(i,end="\n")
            print("")
        else:
            print("All IP's are Rechable from " + file_name)
    return
'''
'''

def open_file(file_name, rechable, unrechable):
    df = pd.read_excel("D:/Network/"+file_name+".xlsx")
    col_IP = df.loc[:, "IP"].tolist()
    col_name = df.loc[:, "Location"].tolist()
    check(col_IP, col_name, rechable, unrechable)
    return
'''
'''

def check(col_IP, col_name, rechable, unrechable):
    for ip in range(len(col_IP)):
        response = os.popen(f"ping {col_IP[ip]} ").read()
        if("Request timed out." or "unreachable") in response:
            print(response)
            unrechable.append(str(col_IP[ip] + " at " + col_name[ip]))
        else:
            print(response)
            rechable.append(str(col_IP[ip] + " at " + col_name[ip]))
    return
'''
'''
def main1():
  while(True):
      start()
      print("Goint to Sleep for 2Hrs")
      time.sleep(60)

def qu():
  while(True):
      if(keyboard.is_pressed('q')):
          print("exit")
          os._exit
'''
'''  

file_list = ["ISP" , "NVR"]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    

    p2 = Thread(target=main1)
    p3 = Thread(target=qu)

    p2.start()
    p3.start()
```

I have created 2 threads here one runs the main script the other looks for keyboard interrupt. But once q is pressed only one of the threads terminates. I later found out it is impossible to terminate both threads at one and I am completely lost at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a queue to a thread that listens to any keyboard interrupts and once the condition is met adds it to the queue.

```
def qu1():
    while(True):
        if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
            qu_main.put("q")
            print("added q")
            break
        else:
            pass
    return
```

Next I put my sleep timer in a loop.
I wanted my script to execute in 2hr intervals therefore I added a 1s timer and looped it 7200 times.

```
while(x < 7200):
            if(not qu_main.empty()):
                if(qu_main.get() == 'q'):
                    print("ending the Cycle")
                    return
                else:
                    print("sleep")
                    x += 1
                    time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print("sleep")
                x += 1
                time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should listen for the keyboard interrupts in the main thread. Then you can call `p2.join()` upon interrupt.

But why do it with `q`? Doesn't `Ctrl+C` work for you? That is the default interrupt. Then you don't have to implement any other special logic.

Comment: the problem in the main thread is that even if I do listen for the inputs once it goes into sleep I wont be able to terminate the program

Answer (score 2):

You can use `timedInput()`

First run these commands:

`python3 install pip`

`pip install --upgrade pip`

`pip3 install pytimedinput`

Make sure you import it:

```py
from pytimedinput import timedInput
```

Quit script:

```py
var_name,timesup = timedInput("",60,False,0)
if ((var_name)[0])=="q":
  quit()
```

Comment: If you want to immediatly quit, you can use `,endCharacters="q")` as the last arguement. Like this: `var_name,timesup = timedInput("",60,False,0,endCharacters="q")`